# Which TypeScript class does SVG's beginElement() method belong to?

Tags: type-conversion, typescript

SVG has a [`beginElement()` method](http://ryanarn.blogspot.com/2011/04/svg-animation-and-svg-dom-beginelement.html). But I cant seem to locate it in lib.d.ts.
Currently I have to cast the variable to 'any' to call it from TypeScript without any errors.

Can someone point me to the exact TypeScript class that contains that method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition for that is not present. However you can quite easily add it yourself as typescript interfaces are open-ended:

```
interface SVGElement extends Element {
    beginElement(): SVGElement;
}

var foo = new SVGElement();
foo.beginElement();
```

Comment: The answer is good but I just want to add that methods like this are often added to lib.d.ts in later releases.  When that happens you'll get an error about "duplicate definition."  Just delete the newly redundant line and you're good to keep going.

Answer (score 0):

If you use animationTransform you should extend SVGAnimationElement:

```
interface SVGAnimateTransformElement extends SVGAnimationElement {
      beginElement(): SVGAnimateTransformElement;
}
```